# How do I recognize that Crippling Suplex is coming when fighting Hans and Franz?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I got one shotted by Hans'gar and Franzok HC today multiple times, because I could not recognize when they actually do [Crippling Suplex](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=156938/crippling-suplex). The cast bar is showing up once they already grabbed you or the other tank. In case of the other tank, I can use Divine Protection or other defensive cooldowns, but both need to do that, before being grabbed.

I do use Deadly Boss Mods, but the warning there is unreliable and often too early, resulting in Divine Protection running out before I actually was hit by the damage. For what it is worth, I have ~440k Life buffed, a GS of 677 and I am a Protection Paladin.

[This guide](http://www.icy-veins.com/wow/hans-gar-and-franzok-strategy-guide-normal-heroic) on icy-veins is inconclusive about that, unfortunately.

Comment: As an aside, this will be easier in 6.1 when they fix the bug that prevents you from using CDs during Suplex.  PTR testing is wrapping up, so ETA is soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crippling Suplex with you being picked up always comes when your boss leaves the combat area to active the searing plates or stamps. That is your cue to use a cooldown.

Comment: Guess that has to do for now until this mess is fixed. We got another raid on tomorrow, hope 6.1 hits us tomorrow morning on maintenance.

Comment: Don't get your hopes up too high. Looks like one or two more weeks.

Comment: Did you guys already kill them on HC? How do your tanks handle this inconvenience? DP or the Guardian only run 8 seconds and the suplex cast is around 3 seconds at least, so activating it too early can really mess you up.

Comment: I am only dps and not sure how exactly our tanks are doing it. I will ask them later if I don't forget.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Patch has been announced for Feb 24th.